# ng-file-upload is not working properly with each element in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-file-upload

I am trying to upload multiple files for each object in ng-repeat in an array.But when I try to upload files for 2nd/3rd object(other than the first element) in the Array, all the files getting uploaded for the first element.

In below code

```
<tbody ng-repeat="book in books">
<tr>
<td>
  <div class="row" style="padding: 15px;">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
      <h4 >{{ book.seller_name }}</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row' id="tb">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" align="center">
          <p class="custom" style="width: 100px;"><b>Total paid price</b><input style="height: 44px;" ng-model="book.paid_price" class="form-control" ng-disabled="!book.editable" type="number" required></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" align="center" style="padding-left: 0px;">
          <p style="width: 123px;"><b>Book Number(s)</b><textarea ng-model="book.book_number" class="form-control" ng-disabled="!book.editable" type="text" style="height: 44px;" required></textarea><p style="display:none;">{{book.book_number}}</p></p>
          <div ng-if="editDisabled" class="text-center">
            <div ng-hide="book.image_urls.length == 0">
              <a class="btn btn-primary" id="view_image" style="cursor:pointer;" ng-click="viewbookInvoiceImages(book)">View Book Invoices</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          </br>
          <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit"
              ng-click="submitBookDetail(book)" ng-disabled="!book.editable && !book.enableSubmit">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" align="center" style="margin-top: 17px;padding-left: 2px">
          <input ng-disabled="!book.editable" class="form-control inputFile" align="center" type="file" name="file" id="file" ngf-select ng-model="book.picFiles" ngf-keep="'distinct'" ngf-multiple="true" ngf-change="upload($book.picFiles)"
          accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="8MB" 
          ngf-model-invalid="errorFile" ngf-capture='camera'/>
          <label for="file" class="fileInputLabel" style="height: 45px;width: 120px;" ng-class="{'disableUploadBtn': !book.editable}">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="17" viewBox="0 0 20 17">
              <path d="M10 0l-5.2 4.0 1.1-.4 1.3-.9l.6-3.1c.1-.5-.2-1.2-.7-1.5z"></path>
            </svg>
            Capture Invoices
          </label>
           <i ng-show="errorFile.size" class="fileUploadErrCls" >File too large{{errorFile.size / 1000000|number:1}}MB: max 8M</i><br/>
          <ul class="response">
            <li  ng-repeat="pic in book.picFiles">
              <div>
                {{pic.name}}
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

My controller code for the submit is

```
$scope.submitBookDetail = function(book){
  console.log(book);
  $scope.bookId = book.id
  var images_to_upload = [];
 if(book.picFiles.length !== 0){
   var isInvalidFileFormat = false;
   angular.forEach(book.picFiles , function(picFile){
     var tempObj = {};
     if(picFileTypes.indexOf(picFile.type) === -1){
       $scope.err_msg = 'Please select file of JPEG/PNG type.';
       $scope.succ_display='ng-hide';
       $scope.err_display='ng-show';
       isInvalidFileFormat = true;
     }
     tempObj.image = picFile;
     images_to_upload.push(tempObj);
   });

  images_to_upload.upload = Upload.upload({
    url: ENV.apiEndPoint + 'books/' + $scope.bookId + '?token='+authSrv.getToken(),
    method: 'PUT',
    data: { id: $scope.bookId,
            images : images_to_upload,
            paid_price: book.paid_price,
            book_number: (book.book_number || '')
          }
  });

  images_to_upload.upload.then(function (response) {
    $scope.editDisabled=true;
    book.editable=false;
    book.percent=response.data.percent;
    book.image_urls = response.data.image_urls;
    book.picFiles = []
    book.enableSubmit = false;
    book.succ_msg = 'Book details are successfully updated ';
   },function (response) {
    $scope.editDisabled=true;
    book.editable=false;
    book.err_msg = response.data.message
    book.enableSubmit = false;
   });
}
```

I guess this is because of the **id='file'** while uploading. For each index in the loop the id is same, that's why it is assuming for the first element and uploading it irrespective of other indexes. If i give **id='file{{#index}}'** , the button itself not working.I spent whole day and couldnot find anything, Can anyone please suggest what would be the solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving unique id in input name , id and label , It should be same id for label attribute **for** and input attribute **id**

```
<input ng-disabled="!book.editable" class="form-control inputFile" align="center" type="file" name="file{{$index}}" id="file{{$index}}" ngf-select ng-model="book.picFiles" ngf-keep="'distinct'" ngf-multiple="true" ngf-change="upload($book.picFiles)"
          accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="8MB" 
          ngf-model-invalid="errorFile" ngf-capture='camera'/>
<label for="file{{$index}}" class="fileInputLabel" style="height: 45px;width: 120px;" ng-class="{'disableUploadBtn': !book.editable}">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="17" viewBox="0 0 20 17">
              <path d="M10 0l-5.2 4.0 1.1-.4 1.3-.9l.6-3.1c.1-.5-.2-1.2-.7-1.5z"></path>
            </svg>
            Capture Invoices
          </label>
```

Comment: Tried, its not working. input field is only allowing id=file and name=file. Other than that its not taking any other value.

Comment: This is an issue with the library, I have resolved it in a different way without modifying the library. Earlier i can have multiple table rows expanded and then i upload, which gives me the above error. Now i have expanded only one table row,by making other rows collapse, it is working fine now.